# custom share image for fb, g+ and twitter using open graph

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph, google-plus

Is it possible to have a custom share image for Facebook, Google+ and Twitter?

I've already set up the open graph tags in the head of the document.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

For Facebook:

`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=url" target="_blank" ><img src="fb-img"/></a>`

For Twitter:

`<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<my-status>" target="_blank"><img src="twitter-img" /></a>`

Still looking for google+

By the way, any difference with sharer.php v/s share.php for Facebook?

Comment: Something like this?
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=url" target="_blank">
<img src="/images/mycustombutton.jpg" /></a>

Comment: thanks, any difference between share.php and sharer.php?

Comment: Google plus button is like this:
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=url" >
    <img src="/icons/gplus.jpg" alt="Google+" title="Google+"/>
</a>

Comment: There's no difference between share.hp and sharer.php they both redirect to the same url

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that!

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution to implement custom share button with Facebutton:
Go to facebook developers page and there you will have to read the following article which will explain you how to use meta tags (HTML) on the head of your page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Basically you need to add a Share Button on your page, right?. So, what you need to do is first of all, add the meta tags that page ask you for on the head of your page. Then everything is so easy. After facebook provides you with the code for the share button, now when you click on it, it will show you the image you specified on your meta tags. Take a look at that page and you'll see how easy is to implement it.

Twitter still i haven't implement it yet neither for google :(